# error 1 Windows 8 or higher is required to build for Windows or Windows Phone

Tags: visual-studio-2013

error1  Windows 8 or higher is required to build for Windows or Windows Phone.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\CordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets   136 5   BlankCordovaApp1

Comment: What did you try to accomplish, what exactly did you do, what OS are you running...? Some more info sure wouldn't hurt.

Comment: run javascript,this is windows 7

Comment: This is debug's result.

Answer (score 1):

> Windows 8 or higher is required to build for Windows or Windows Phone.

If you are running Windows 7 the answer is right there.

Comment: So,I should run windows 8?

Comment: If you want to build software with Visual Studio 12 for Windows 8 you'll have to